# How to escape a dot in emmet

Tags: react-native, escaping, code-snippets, emmet

I am using Atom to write a react-native application. Basically I need a snippet that expands to:

```
  <TabBarIOS>
    <TabBarIOS.Item>
    </TabBarIOS.Item>
    <TabBarIOS.Item
    </TabBarIOS.Item>
  </TabBarIOS>
```

if I try something like: `TabBarIOS>TabBarIOS.Item*2` it uses the dot to add a className attribute, so it produces:

```
 <TabBarIOS>
  <TabBarIOS className="Item"></TabBarIOS>
  <TabBarIOS className="Item"></TabBarIOS>
</TabBarIOS>
```

The official documentation includes syntax to escape "|" and "$" with "\", sadly that does not work for dots. Is there a way to escape that dot in order to get it included in the tag name?

Comment: have you found the answer for this?

Comment: Need Answers pleez